# How to enable and disable checkboxes in kendo treeview?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a logic when user select parent i want to disable children nodes,So with below implementation when i select parent checkbox all parents and child are disabling. I just want to disable related children and when i uncheck parent all childrens should be enabled.

So far tried code...

Config.js

```
},geoLocationTreeConfig : {
        template: '{{dataItem.text}}',
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: false,
            template: '<input  {{dataItem.disabled}} type=\'checkbox\' ng-click=\'updateGeoLoctionList(dataItem)\' value=\'true\' />'
        }
```

Tree.js

```
//If the parent item is checked, disable all the children
          if(geoLocation.items){
            $.each(geoLocation.items,function(index,location){
                $scope.disableChild = true;
            });
        }
    }else{
        selectedGeoLocations.splice(pos,1);
        selectedGeoLocationIds.splice($.inArray(geoLocation.id,selectedGeoLocationIds),1);

        //If the parent item is unchecked,  enable the children
        if(geoLocation.items){
            $.each(geoLocation.items,function(index,location){
                $scope.disableChild = false;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add a plunkr to your current solution?

Comment: Sorry cant use plunker and jsfiddle , any help here will be appreciated! thanks